# Save xml header with CComPtr<IXMLDOMDocument> (C++)

Tags: c++, xml, msxml

I use atl and CComPtr, like this:

```
CComPtr<IXMLDOMDocument> xml_doc;
HRESULT hr = xml_doc.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(DOMDocument))
...
HRESULT hr = xml_doc->createElement(CComBSTR(element_name.c_str()), &element);
...
etc
```

When I invoke xml_doc->save it saves xml without header. What the easiest way to add  header?

Answer (score 3):

solved:

```
HRESULT hr;

CComPtr<IXMLDOMProcessingInstruction> proc_instr;
hr = xml_out->createProcessingInstruction(L"xml", L"version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"", &proc_instr);
if (FAILED(hr))
    throw std::exception("Failed to create IXMLDOMDocument processing instruction");


CComPtr<IXMLDOMNode> first_child;
hr = xml_out->get_firstChild(&first_child);
if (FAILED(hr))
    throw std::exception("Failed to get first child of IXMLDOMDocument");

hr = xml_out->insertBefore(proc_instr, CComVariant(first_child), NULL);
if (FAILED(hr))
    throw std::exception("Failed to insert IXMLDOMDocument processing instruction");


hr = xml_out->save(CComVariant(header->output_file.c_str()));
if (FAILED(hr))
    throw std::exception("Failed to save response XML to '" + header->output_file + "'");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms755439(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: THANK YOU! I've been looking for this for days!